# add jsr80 on maven

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to add jsr80 with maven on eclipse on linux(Lubuntu).

My pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Source.Web.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>EjemploMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>EjemploMaven</name>
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
       <groupId>jsr80</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr80</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/jsr80.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>jsr80_ri</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsr80_ri</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/jsr80_ri.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>jsr80_environment</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr80_environment</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/${jsr80.env}</systemPath>
      </dependency>  
   <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

I have tried mvn clean, mvn update dependeces ...
Log4j it's addes fine

The error message is

```
Missing artifact jsr80:jsr80:jar:1.0:system
Missing artifact jsr80_ri:jsr80_ri:jar:1.0:system
Missing artifact jsr80_environment:jsr80_environment:jar:1.0.1:system
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by different interpolation rules inside the `systemPath` tag.

It's anyway better to first install your artifacts as normal dependencies to a repository:

- local: use [`mvn install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html)
- remote: use [`mvn deploy:deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/disabling-timestamps-suffix.html) (this need some more configuration in settings.xml)

Then change your dependencies to default (compile) scope:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jsr80</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr80</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jsr80_ri</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr80_ri</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jsr80_environment</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr80_environment</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

This approach has the effect that you need to use a repository to share it with others. On the other hand, it allows you to avoid committing binaries with code which is harmful for several reasons.